# Change Date Format from an array in SQL SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-spark, databricks

I have a column **updated_at** that returns an array

`["2019-01-05T17:28:32.506-05:00","2019-06-15T13:22:02.625-04:00"]`

But I want the output date format like this 2019-01-03.

How can I accomplish this in sql databricks?

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a JSON array, not like a native Postgres array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unnest and cast that as a date:

```
with ts_array as
     (select array['2019-01-05T17:28:32.506-05:00','2019-06-15T13:22:02.625-04:00'] as tsa)
select unnest(tsa)::date from ts_array ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "**date_trunc**" SQL function to get the output in date format.

date_trunc(fmt, ts) - Returns timestamp ts truncated to the unit specified by the format model fmt. fmt should be one of [“YEAR”, “YYYY”, “YY”, “MON”, “MONTH”, “MM”, “DAY”, “DD”, “HOUR”, “MINUTE”, “SECOND”, “WEEK”, “QUARTER”]

Examples:

```
> SELECT date_trunc('YEAR', '2015-03-05T09:32:05.359');
 2015-01-01 00:00:00
> SELECT date_trunc('MM', '2015-03-05T09:32:05.359');
 2015-03-01 00:00:00
> SELECT date_trunc('DD', '2015-03-05T09:32:05.359');
 2015-03-05 00:00:00
> SELECT date_trunc('HOUR', '2015-03-05T09:32:05.359');
 2015-03-05 09:00:00
```

**Reference:** [Databricks - SQL Functions](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions.html#date_trunc).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually tried that, but doesn't work on the array. But yeah that would've been the solution :)